# Google Nexus 7 (2013 Wi-Fi) Boot freeze, no recovery options working

Tags: boot, nexus-7, bootloader-lock

I bought a Google Nexus 7 2013 edition, Wi-Fi only, from a yard sale. I have no clue what the previous owner did or tried but I cannot get it to boot. I'm not by any means an Android expert so if it seems I'm missing something basic, it's quite possible.

Basic Symptoms and Problems:
-Power on -> stuck at "Google" logo screen
-Recovery mode -> the Android guy on his back with the red "!"
-Cannot wipe data/factory reset or clear cache partition as both result in a  bunch of mount failures (e.g. "Failed to mount /cache (Invalid argument)
-Cannot unlock (freezes on "erasing user data" for indefinite time)
-Cannot use adb to send OTA as it sends the package but can't mount partitions and results in "Installation aborted"

What I CAN do:
-use adb and can see the device
-use fastboot and see the device

I have PC drivers installed. Running Windows 10 on my PC. I don't care about the data or anything. I just wanted to wipe and factory restore this device. It physically looks to be in great condition if relevant.

I'm not sure what my next step should be or if I'm working towards the right direction. Pretty much every solution I've check either gives me errors or every thread is abandoned without solution.

Comment: Throw it in the trash. Its a 5 year old device that were junk after 2 to start with.

Comment: Well with that mentality, there's a lot of crap that would get thrown away. But that wasn't my question.